# Table caption spanning two columns

Tags: tables, sectioning, floats, page-breaking

I have an appendix section in my document, and I have to put a `table` after that. The problem is that I intend to use `table*`, but if I use that it would ignore `table*[h]` and will place the table on top of next page leaving a whole blank page after section appendix. 
And if I use `table` together with `[h]` it does place the table right after the appendix section name, but the problem is the caption now is one column as the document is basically two column.

So, now I have two solutions, first, bring the `table*` in such a a way that it starts right after appendix section. But I know that `[h]` does not work with `table*`.

Second solution might be to use `table[h]` and make the caption span two columns so that it does not look bad.

How can I achieve any two of these, or any other solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sounds like you want

```
\twocolumn[
\section{foo}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
....
]
....
```

so the heading and table are in a one-column block before the two column text starts

Comment: do you mean something like this?

\twocolumn[

\section{apeendix}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}

\end{tabular}

]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with David's idea, but in the opposite way. Before declaring the table I temporarily made the document as a single column document.